# Nice answer badge weirdness. Possible bug

Tags: discussion, badges, nice-answer

I'm not sure whether this should be reported as a bug, but the behavior is inconsistent.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295264/starx?tab=stats) has 10 'Nice Answer' badges. But if you look at the answers (sorted by vote)  or the [details](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=295264) page and actually go through the answers, there are only 2 answers with 10 votes. Some of the answers are actually zero score (-1/+1), these were answers posted by the user to questions he asked. Is this a bug or is this intended behavior? And if it's intended behavior, how does it work?

**EDIT**

And it's the same with his 'Nice Question' badge as well. Only 3 questions with >= +10 votes, but badge awarded 9 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug's with the user, not the software. The user in question has (so far) had over a dozen accounts merged in with his.

With enough sock puppets, it's easy to get Nice Answer badges.

Badges only get taken away if the issue gets forced in some fashion; the good news, though, is that he won't earn any further Nice Answers badges until he's earned the ones he has now.

Comment: Oh, I see. So when accounts get merged, don't the answers they provided (which earned the badge initially) get transferred as well?

Comment: @JohnP - The answers, yes. But if user2 through user12 all voted for user1's answer, and then the users are merged, their votes no longer count.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot about the upvotes. Thanks, that cleared the confusion. I'll remove the bug tag and mark this as answered