# User with unwarranted badges

Tags: discussion, badges, revoked-badges

I am curious about how [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234175/victor-t) got sooo lucky. Just look:

[image]

But wait .... that is not all. As you see, he managed to get **two Reversal badges in the same day** ... with posts scoring just 3 upvotes (when 20 are rquired):

---

### [image]

### [image]

There should be something strange going on (perhaps accounts merging?), because both answers were posted on Dec 29, but on the activity page for the user those events are not recorded.

So ... Twin Reversal badges for all! ... or an explanation?

Comment: Am I wrong, or can't the same be said for those Necromancer badges this user earned within five minutes of each other on Dec 30th?  Seems something just ain't right there.

Comment: Strange indeed, but what were you doing looking at a random guys activity from 6 months ago?

Comment: also, Mortarboard with 20 rep.

Comment: @John I was reading this answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95579/make-questions-with-bad-reputation-not-indexed-in-google/95580#95580 and as it links to the Reversal badge awards, I started clicking randomly (and mindlessly :) and then I noticed this user being awarded _twice in a row_. BTW the Reversal badge is my favorite, and I already posted here on meta a proposal to NOT delete those Q&A... declined (almost)

Comment: @Wether, didn't we discuss this before? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91513/an-interesting-test-case-for-delete-vote-numbers/91515#comment-228214

Comment: @mmyers Sorry. I don't remember reading your comment before. The "new" inbox super-ortho-mega-collider sometimes drive me nuts! Really strange nobody noticed (after reading your comment) that that user got both badges the same day.

Comment: He'll be posting an angry "where did my reputation go?" question on meta in 3...2...1...

Comment: Ok that makes sense.

Comment: One note not made by others yet... even if that member will now get 20 upvotes on  answer to -5 question he will **not** get the badge again - twice. Only the third time he will meet the badge requirements will he get the third one.

Comment: @Shadow It's like a loan ... but no interest

Comment: @Wether yeah.. I agree it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've noticed this kind of activity before, talked about it in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87797/nice-answer-badge-weirdness-possible-bug). This user most likely had his accounts merged. So although he lost the rep from the other accounts, the badges would hang around since badges aren't automatically withdrawn when you fall below the criteria for meeting them.

Comment: But ... the questions were voted only thrice ...and you need 20 upvotes for the badge ...

Comment: Yes those are the actual (real) votes, but keep in mind that his sock puppets could have upvoted his answer and when the system detects it, it automatically removes the suspect votes. But the badges would still be around since they aren't automatically removed.

Comment: wow ... in that case he was quite busy on those days :)

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned, these badges were obtained with the help of sockpuppets.  We don't have an automated process for revoking badges, but I manually revoked them.

Answer (score 8):

Luck had nothing to do with it—it can be hard work to run that many sock puppets!

If you look more closely, you'll see that he [got most of those badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234175/victor-t?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_badges) last December—and only a few since. That was the point at which the socks were discovered and merged into his account.

It's rare for badges to be revoked, and it appears it hasn't happened in this instance.

Comment: Ok. It is a pity. I was about to ask for my twin reversal badges too. Thanks!

Comment: I think I brought it up in the lounge but got no response. Is there a standard process?

Comment: @mmyers, if it was by his sockpuppets, the standard process should include tar and feathers (and a picture of the result on the front page). ;-).

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=995915#995915 -- apparently I asked everyone *but* Dori. :)

Comment: @mmyers - There's no standard process, or even a non-standard GUI process. But revoking badges has been done (albeit rarely), as mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75032/5k-reputation-loss-in-one-day-how-big-is-that/75034#comment-181923), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80907/how-did-i-get-a-mortarboard-badge-when-ive-only-earned-95-rep-for-the-whole-mont/80977#80977), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81127/my-mortarboard-badge-just-disappeared/81128#81128) (and note that all these were by devs).